# Place content at the bottom of div relative to image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is intended to be an image preview along with text.
I have two divs: one with an image and one with text. The image needs to be square size and fill the whole container

The code currently is

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://quarknet.de/fotos/blumen/wildblumen/graeser-im-quadrat.jpg" alt="" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="top">Top</div>
        <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m1sbhnwe/

And it is intended for full-screen, so you need to drag the preview wider to see the effect.

Now I need the div with the top class to always stay at the top of that div and the div with the bottom class to always stay at the bottom of the parent div at image level. That means the bottom div should align with the lower edge of the picture.

If I add `position:absolute;bottom:0` to that div it just goes to the top. How can I achive the effect I want?

Comment: Why do you have two bootstrap col-6? Wouldn't it be easier to put the top and bottom divs in the same div as the image? Do you want the alignment to change according to resize?

Comment: what is it suppose to look like , http://jsfiddle.net/m1sbhnwe/1/?

Comment: It should look like this http://i.imgur.com/mHLXfhG.png

Answer (score 1):

I don't quiet understand the effect your going for.

If the text is appearing at the top it ussually points to the parent div having a height of 0px;

if you are floating .col-md-6 then that could cause a problem calculating height. In which case you would want to add a  after the last .col-md-6

if you are using a absolute positioned .col-md-6 then the size cannot be calculated and you will have to come up with a fixed width/height;

Here is a solution kinda that would work if the .row is full screen...

```
.row {
    position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;
}
.col-md-6 {
    position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
.col-md-6 img {
    height:100%;
}
.col-md-6 .top {
    position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
}
.col-md-6 .bottom {
    position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
}
```

the fiddle you provided has no css in it, It would help if you added some CSS to show the problem you are having.

UPDATED FOR COMMENT;

```
.col-md-6 {
    float:left; height:100%; position:relative;
}
.col-md-6 img {
    height:100%;
}
.col-md-6 .top {
    position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
}
.col-md-6 .bottom {
    position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px;
}
```